# ASP.NET Entity Framework - DropDownListFor Enum values

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

I have a class like so:

```
namespace CentralParkVIPPreview.Models
{
    [Table("CP-VIP-Preview")]
    public class CP_VIP_Preview
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Occupancy Timeline")]
        [Required]
        public string occupancyTimeline { get; set; }
    }

    public class Homefront : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CP_VIP_Preview> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public enum occupancyTimeline : int
    {
        TwelveMonths = 12,
        FourteenMonths = 14,
        SixteenMonths = 16,
        EighteenMonths = 18
    }

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static SelectList ToSelectList(this occupancyTimeline enumObj)
        {
            var values = from occupancyTimeline e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(occupancyTimeline))
                         select new { Id = e, Name = string.Format("{0} Months", Convert.ToInt32(e)) };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }
    }

}
```

What I am trying to do is the following, take the values in the enum occupancyTimeline method (12, 14, 16, 18) and use them for a dropdown menu like so:

```
@model CentralParkVIPPreview.Models.CP_VIP_Preview
@using CentralParkVIPPreview.Models

@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupancyTimeline, Model.occupancyTimeline.ToSelectList());
```

my problem is I am getting this error:

```
'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToSelectList' and the best extension method overload 'CentralParkVIPPreview.Models.MyExtensions.ToSelectList(CentralParkVIPPreview.Models.occupancyTimeline)' has some invalid arguments
```

on this line:

```
Model.occupancyTimeline.ToSelectList()
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your extension method is for a enum type and you are trying to use it for a string, you could try adding a new property to your model to parse the string to enum, something like this:

```
          public occupancyTimeline occupancyTimelineType
            {
                get
                {
                    return Enum.Parse(occupancyTimeline, occupancyTimeline);

                }
            }
```

in your cshtml :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupancyTimeline,Model.occupancyTimelineType.ToSelectList());
```

Comment: I am confused, what would my whole class look like? @Aldo

Comment: I replaced `public string occupancyTimeline { get; set; }` with `public occupancyTimeline occupancyTimelineType
            {
                get
                {
                    return Enum.Parse(occupancyTimeline, occupancyTimeline);

                }
            }` but I get this error `'CentralParkVIPPreview.Models.occupancyTimeline' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable' `

Comment: please see the code of the class, i did some changes it should works !

Comment: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Enum.Parse(System.Type, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: Make sure that the first argument is the enum type of occupancyTimelineTypes and the second the string value Enum.Parse(yourEnumType, yourString);

Comment: I still dont understand

Answer (score 0):

```
[Table("CP-VIP-Preview")]
    public class CP_VIP_Preview
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Occupancy Timeline")]
        [Required]
        public string occupancyTimeline { get; set; }


        public occupancyTimelineTypes occupancyTimelineType
        {
            get
            {
                return Enum.Parse(occupancyTimelineTypes, occupancyTimeline);

            }
        }
    }

    public class Homefront : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<CP_VIP_Preview> Data { get; set; }
    }

    public enum occupancyTimelineTypes : int
    {
        TwelveMonths = 12,
        FourteenMonths = 14,
        SixteenMonths = 16,
        EighteenMonths = 18
    }

    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static SelectList ToSelectList(this occupancyTimelineTypes enumObj)
        {
            var values = from occupancyTimeline e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(occupancyTimeline))
                         select new { Id = e, Name = string.Format("{0} Months", Convert.ToInt32(e)) };
            return new SelectList(values, "Id", "Name", enumObj);
        }
    }
```

in your html :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.occupancyTimeline,Model.occupancyTimelineType.ToSelectList());
```

Comment: I get this error `CentralParkVIPPreview.Models.occupancyTimeline' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'`